# Azure SQL active long running system transactions for 2 weeks

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have executed a simple query :

```
select * from sys.dm_tran_active_transactions
```

and I get the following output with suspicious system looking transactions that are running for 2 weeks . I can't find information about them online .
[image]
What are these transactions ,are they normal ?

Comment: Are they causing you any kind of problems ? Or you are just curious about what Microsoft does "behind the scene" ?

Comment: `transaction_type` 2 is for read-only transactions. If you suspect that these may be causing problems, describing the problem would be helpful. If you're just looking around, and trying to learn more, that's important to include additional details in your question, as well as helping answerers understand what you already know and what you're trying to learn/understand

Comment: @DominiqueBoucher the question is what are these transactions , and if they are normal . Searching for `PopulateLockOrdinalsForAllDBs` does not show any results on google...

Comment: @DominiqueBoucher 
I am trying to debug  some me blocked queries from our app that generate dynamic queries . We don't have timeouts on our queries  from the client side. The prolem is that it doesn't happen all the time .

Comment: @OvidiuBuligan Its not possible to determine what's causing your queries to be blocked based on this information. Use Adam Mechanic's [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com/) to show you what's blocking your queries and / or what they're waiting on, while they're running.

Comment: @J.D.  the sp_WhoIsActive  sp looks to greatly help . I will need to test it out when blocks happen again.

Comment: @OvidiuBuligan Yes, it's an awesome tool for an overall view of what's currently running on the server, and how those things are performing or what's their bottlenecks. Just make sure you download the version that supports Azure SQL Database.